# Android CoroutineScope Auto Cancel after It Finishes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-threading, coroutinescope

I want to know whether `coroutineScope` will be auto-canceled after its work is finished. Say I create a `coroutineScope` in a custom class **Rather Than** `ViewModel` class or `Fragment / Activity` class:

```
class MyClass {
    private val backgroundScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    fun doSomething() = backgroundScope.launch {
        //do background work
    }
}
```

In this case, after the **background work** is done, would `backgroundScope` auto-cancel itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `CoroutineScope` consists of a `CoroutineContext`. A `CoroutineContext` consist of 2 primary elements,a `Job` and a `ContinuationInterceptor`(usually just a `CoroutineDispatcher`), other elements are `CoroutineExceptionHandler` and `CoroutineName`.

If a coroutine finishes it won't cancel the scope (that is its Job).
Even if you cancel the coroutine's job it won't cancel the scope (that is its Job). Because **each time you fire a coroutine using a specific scope, the coroutine's job becomes a child job of the scope's job.**

In your case `backgroundScope`, you did not specify a `Job` yourself, if you dig into the source code, you'll see that in the absence of a `Job`, a `Job` instance is provided..

```
val coroutineJob = backgroundScope.launch { ... }
```

When this `coroutineJob` finishes or is cancelled, it will not cancel the `Job` inside the `backgroundScope`, therefore the `backgroundScope` won't be cancelled.

Answer (score 5):

It won't auto-cancel. It stays open for any number of jobs to be launched on it. However, you may want to give the scope a `SupervisorJob()` as its root context if you don't want it to be killed by any child jobs completing exceptionally. If that happened, subsequent coroutines on the scope wouldn't start.

```
private val backgroundScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
```

The reason `lifecycleScope` and `viewModelScope` are automatically cancelled when their associated class is destroyed is because under the hood, Jetpack subscribes to the lifecycle of the associated class and manually cancels the scope in `onDestroy()`.